# Using .replace method in Python for slicing text

Tags: python, tkinter

I learn how string indexing, slicing, & replace method works, which is what I use in this code.

I was able to remove the first 41 characters in this link `http://urlshortener.io/s/1234abc/?s=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsome_contents%2F`. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax4jK.png) the result.

Here's the code:

```
 from tkinter import *
 window = Tk()
 window.title("URL Slicer")
 window.geometry('525x100')
 lbl = Label(window, text="URL")
 lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
 txt = Entry(window,width=75)
 txt.grid(column=1, row=0)

 def clicked():
    sliced = txt.get()
    lbl.configure(text= sliced[41:])

btn = Button(window, text="Start", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=2, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

However, I still want to get rid of those "%2F" so I added .replace method:

here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
 window = Tk()
 window.title("URL Slicer")
 window.geometry('525x100')
 lbl = Label(window, text="URL")
 lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
 txt = Entry(window,width=75)
 txt.grid(column=1, row=0)

 def clicked():
     sliced = txt.get()
     sliced.replace('%2F', '/')  //added .replace
     lbl.configure(text= sliced[41:])

 btn = Button(window, text="Start", command=clicked)
 btn.grid(column=2, row=0)
 window.mainloop()
```

(but result of the second code is the the same with the first one)

the link should just be: example.com/some_contents/

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is not an "in-place" method; instead, it returns a copy. Therefore, you need to assign back to your variable for the operation to store your result:

```
x = 'http://urlshortener.io/s/1234abc/?s=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsome_contents%2F'    
x = x.replace('%2F', '/')

print(x)

http://urlshortener.io/s/1234abc/?s=https%3A//example.com/some_contents/
```

A better solution is to use the purpose-built `urllib`:

```
from urllib import parse

x = 'http://urlshortener.io/s/1234abc/?s=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsome_contents%2F'

x = parse.unquote(x)

print(x)

http://urlshortener.io/s/1234abc/?s=https://example.com/some_contents/
```

Comment: Both in your example, you set X = http://urlshortener.io/s/1234abc/?s=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsome_contents%2F' (only one link able to be sliced). I want to slice multiple different links of the same kind when I paste them in the 'txt = Entry(window,width=75)' then click start button.

Comment: Use a function and a list comprehension (or `map`) to apply a function to a sequence of inputs. I've never used `tkinter`, but I don't think the problem you are facing is specific to `tkinter`.